# Guidelines for passing stl containers to C functions

Tags: c++, c, stl

We're migrating to modern c++ with stl containers. But the old c with classes style persists. One of the hardest areas to refactor are the interfaces to C api's.

```
// foo_types_list (array terminated by FOO_TYPE_NONE)
enum FooTypes find_best_footype(const enum FooTypes *foo_types_list,
                                        unsigned int capabilities);

std::vector<FooTypes> myFooTypes{ FOO_TYPE_A, FOO_TYPE_ZZ, FOO_TYPE_B };

FooTypes foo = find_best_footype( &myFooTypes.front(), 42); // fail, not terminated.
```

What is the best strategy for accommodating these c-api's? I need to terminate the vector to make the call, but I don't want to create unnecessary mutations or copies?

If creating a copy is the only way to go, whats a simple way to make a data structure that will be compatible with the accessors in the C function?

Comment: `std::vector<FooTypes> myFooTypes{ FOO_TYPE_A, FOO_TYPE_ZZ, FOO_TYPE_B, FOO_TYPE_NONE };`, or `myFooTypes.push_back(FOO_TYPE_NONE)`

Comment: Consider using [std::vector::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) instead of `&myFooTypes.front()`.

Comment: "I don't want to create unnecessary mutations or copies" -- if the C function expects a terminated array, then you must either copy the original vector (or at least its contents), or mutate the vector by appending a terminator.  There are no other alternatives.  You could conceivably add the terminator for the duration of the call, then remove it again.

Answer (score -1):

A better solution is to change the interface of `find_best_footype` to take a pointer and a length, rather than assuming a terminator.
(if you have to maintain C compatibility for `find_best_footype`)

Then you can write:

```
FooTypes foo = find_best_footype(myFooTypes.data(), myFooTypes.size(), 42);
```

and not have to change the vector. However, this will require changes elsewhere.

Comment: NO. If I could change the api, I would. But this is not under my control.